# Rails + AngularJS + Not able to access all the columns of the Single Model at View

Tags: json, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my rails application, I am trying to fetch Logged-In-User details using AngularJS service. But while accessing the JSON from server I am getting only few columns rather than all the column present in model.

Only FirstName, LastName, and Primary Email is visible on page and rest of the column are empty.

I tried by direct hit of URL : http://www.example.com/LoggedInUserInfo.json

**Output : {"first_name":"User","last_name":"1","primary_email":"user_one@mailinator.com"}**

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :blood_group,:city,:country,:first_name,:gender,:mobile_number,
  :phone_number,:primary_email,:secondary_email,:state,:street_address,
  :street_address2, :username, :zip_code
```

**Controller Method**

```
def logged_in_user_info
    @user = User.find(1)
    render :json => @user
    #render :json => @user.as_json(:only => [:first_name, :last_name, 
    #                                        :username, :date_of_birth])
end
```

**AngularJS Service**

```
var user_app = angular.module("UserApp", []);
user_app.controller("LoggedInUserInfoCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/LoggedInUserInfo.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.logged_in_user = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error
    });
});
```

**Routes**

```
match '/LoggedInUserInfo' => 'dashboard#logged_in_user_info', :via => [:get]
```

Please suggest some thing to bring all the columns. I think every thing has to be done with Rails Controller. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe this is a Rails problem not Angular.

Comment: Ya I agree with you. But not getting the way to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of googling and lot of changes in controller, got the way to render or fetch specific column at view.

Just created a helper function so that we can call from the view to rearrange or reformat the output that we are calling from the controller. And problem resolved.

```
def logged_in_user_info
  @user = User.find(1)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json do
      render :json => custom_json_for_user(@user)
    end
  end    
end

private
def custom_json_for_user(user_data)
  user_list = 
    { :id => user_data.id,
      :first_name => user_data.first_name.to_s,
      :last_name => user_data.last_name.to_s,
      :date_of_birth => user_data.date_of_birth.to_s,
      :username => user_data.username,
      :primary_email => user_data.primary_email,
      :secondary_email => user_data.secondary_email,
      :gender => user_data.gender
    }    
  user_list.to_json
end
```